# Return a Nan::ObjectWrap from another Nan::ObjectWrap

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

I have two subclasses of `Nan::ObjectWrap`

```
class Zyre: public Nan::ObjectWrap {...}

class ZyreEvent: public Nan::ObjectWrap {...}
```

How can I return a `ZyreEvent` javascript object from a method in `Zyre`?

I have the following method, in which I create a `ZyreEvent`:

```
NAN_METHOD (Zyre::_recv) {
  Zyre *node = Nan::ObjectWrap::Unwrap <Zyre> (info.Holder ());
  ZyreEvent *zyre_event = new ZyreEvent (node->self);
  info.GetReturnValue().Set(zyre_event->Wrap(info.This()));
}
```

But I can't Wrap the zyre_event because `Wrap` is a protected member.

Comment: I'm also struggling with that, did you found a solution (besides the one mentioned below) ? It's a VERY common requirement and there are no examples in the docs, it's incredible.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to return from (subclass of) `Nan::ObjectWrap`'s method instance of another (subclass of) `Nan::ObjectWrap`.

Note: I'm not experienced so this may have faults or be wrong. I've put my sources in brackets where are examples how it's is done I guess.

1. Create `static NewInstance` method in a first class which receives pointer of itself ([NewInstance](https://github.com/tracelytics/node-traceview-bindings/blob/master/src/metadata.cc#L18))
2. Use `v8::External` to wrap first class' C++ object and pass it as an argument for `New` with `argc` and `argv` to first class' constructor ([using v8::External](https://github.com/tracelytics/node-traceview-bindings/blob/master/src/metadata.cc#L22)) ([v8::External doc](http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1External.html))
3. Edit first class' `New` method and handle `info.Length() == 1 && info[0]->IsExternal()` case which is basically copy constructor in this case ([copying passed pointer](https://github.com/tracelytics/node-traceview-bindings/blob/master/src/metadata.cc#L112))
4. Use `...::NewInstance()` in second class to set return value